# How to set Listbox width and size Fixed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel sheet where I am facing an issue with listbox

I have used listbox in my excel sheet and drag the list box to make size bigger and then saved my excel sheet

when I open again the listbox change to its origin size as it was 
I want the width and height to be fixed and static even if I open excel sheet again the size property should not get changed

even I tried vba code to set it but not working

Comment: If you happen to be using ActiveX listbox controls, you might have just run into a known bug where these controls resize themselves. Upon opening the workbook, or even updating the list in it. It might try to implode on itself. You'll have to tinker around with the `Workbook_Open` event if this is your case and set some dimensions on your control. I'm not a fan of ActiveX controls on a worksheet tbh.

Comment: Actually JvdV is right. ActiveX is full of bugs. Stay away from them where ever possible and use Form Controls instead.